# Using matplotlib to retrieve data from excel sheet (.csv) file ;

Tags: python, matplotlib

What do I need to fix?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-56f3e9d938be> in <module>()
     11     plots=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     12     for row in plots:
---> 13         x.append(int(row[1]))
     14         y.append(int(row[2]))
     15 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Open'
```

---

```
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 import csv

 x=[]
 y=[]


with open('/Users/thomasmac/Desktop/Orbital/SPLS.csv', 'r') as csvfile: 
plots=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')   
for row in plots:
    x.append(int(row[0]))
    y.append(int(row[1]))



plt.plot(x,y)

plt.title('SPLS')
plt.ylabel('returns')
plt.xlabel('Share price')

plt.show()
```

Comment: The first word in the file you read in is "Open". "Open" is not a number, hence the error.

Comment: how do i convert open to int or float? , or let the program know open is not a #

Answer (score 0):

We cannot know what to fix, because we don't have full information about the input file. But it seems you are tring to read a csv file with a header. This can easily be done with `numpy.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.genfromtxt("filename.csv",  delimiter=",", skip_header=1, unpack=True)

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.title('SPLS')
plt.ylabel('returns')
plt.xlabel('Share price')

plt.show()
```